# Mimekit adds the rtf as an attachment and not the body

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

Using the following code the rtf body of the winmail.dat file is added as an attachment to the saved email not the body:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    MimeKit.MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(stream);

    int i = 1;
    foreach (MimeKit.MimePart attachment in mimeMessage.Attachments)
    {
        if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(MimeKit.Tnef.TnefPart))
        {
            MimeKit.Tnef.TnefPart tnefPart = (MimeKit.Tnef.TnefPart)attachment;

            MimeKit.MimeMessage tnefMessage = tnefPart.ConvertToMessage();
            tnefMessage.WriteTo(path + $"_tnefPart{i++}.eml");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

---

Looking into the `Attachments` it is not present there but the attachments and the body.rtf file are present in the `BodyParts`. So I can get the body.rtf file like this:

```
int b = 1;
foreach (MimeKit.MimeEntity bodyPart in tnefMessage.BodyParts)
{
    if (!bodyPart.IsAttachment)
    {
        bodyPart.WriteTo(path + $"_bodyPart{b++}.{bodyPart.ContentType.MediaSubtype}");
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Is the body.rtf file isn't true rtf because it starts with the following:

> Content-Type: text/rtf; name=body.rtf
>
> (new line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the `Content-Type` header is because you are writing the MIME envelope as well as the content.

What you need to do is this:

```
int b = 1;
foreach (MimeKit.MimeEntity bodyPart in tnefMessage.BodyParts)
{
    if (!bodyPart.IsAttachment)
    {
        var mime = (MimeKit.MimePart) bodyPart;
        mime.ContentObject.DecodeTo(path + $"_bodyPart{b++}.{bodyPart.ContentType.MediaSubtype}");
    }
}
```